# outlook identity token not valid

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, office-js

We have an O365 tenant, everything is configured out of the box. The tenant is placed in the German cloud and not in global (office.de).

We also have an outlook add-in that uses the [getUserIdentityTokenAsync](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/Office.context.mailbox) from the office.js api.

The add-in takes the user identity token and send it to our server for [validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/validate-an-identity-token) using [AppIdentityToken.Validate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj221907(v=exchg.80).aspx) method but got an error:

> No matching key was found for this token with thumbprint...

The same code works fine for all other tenants.
Any suggestions how to fix this ?

Comment: We have confirmed the repro for this bug on this tenant, and are currently looking into solutions. (no ETA on a fix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be fixed on tenants in the German cloud now. (1/4/2018). To clarify this issue was only in the German cloud. If there is an error on another cloud (currently no known issues), or you are still experiencing invalid tokens from getUserIdentityTokenAsync in German

Comment: We still have issue when trying to get tokens. The request for getting tokens for the discovery service failed with bad request.
Url: https://login.windows.com/common/oauth2/token

`var values = new NameValueCollection
            {
                {"client_id", clientId},
                {"redirect_uri", OAuthRedirectUri},
                {"resource", DiscoveryResource},
                {"grant_type", "authorization_code"},
                {"code", code}
            };


            object result = result = (dynamic)await PostAsync(TokenUrl, values);`

Comment: I clarified the answer that our fix is specific to getUserIdentityTokenAsync. Definitely reply here if you still hit issues with getUserIdentityTokenAsync API. For issues with other token requests, I suggest opening a new post.